# nodejs or apache as first server

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, scalability

I have a website that runs on nodejs and for the blog this website uses wordpress(PHP). So I have decide to use either apache or nodejs as reverse proxy server. If I use node js as reverse proxy then I can easily scale my project by using PM2's cluster feature. But If I use apache then I can not use PM2 to scale up apache. Instead I have to tweak apache process pools and etc to scale up which I feel quite tedious. So what should I choose for reverse proxy apache or nodejs

Comment: Sounds to me like you have made up your mind already.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa No I haven't decided yet

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

For reverse proxy, forget about Apache, you need to run Nginx, it's a tried and true service for reverse proxy setups and it works with PM2:
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/tutorials/pm2-nginx-production-setup

Comment: I want to use pm2 to run multiple instances of the server but if I place the nginx in front of clustered nodejs server. Then there will be only one instance of final server serving the requests which is nginx. So I am affraid it will be a bottleneck.